# Use different activation functions on forward- and backward pass in Keras

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, customization, activation-function

I have a non-differentiable activation function I want to use on the forward-pass. On the backward-pass I want to use the ReLU activation function. I started with a small example, but unfortunately can not find approaches to incur the second activation function into my keras code. Probably something like this isn't even possible with keras? I would be very happy if someone has an idea how to approach this and can give me a hint. Thank you!

```
mnist = tf.keras.datasets.mnist
(train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = mnist.load_data()

test_images_discrete = test_images

train_images = train_images / 255.0
test_images = test_images / 255.0

#my_test_model
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
  tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=16, kernel_size=5, strides=2, padding="valid",
                         activation="relu", input_shape=(28,28,1), use_bias=True),
  tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=3, strides=2, padding="valid",
                         activation="relu", use_bias=True),
  tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(32, activation="relu"),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(10)
])

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
              metrics=["accuracy"])
model.fit(train_images,
          train_labels,
          epochs=5,
          validation_data=(test_images, test_labels))
```

Comment: You can have a look at [Custom Gradients](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/advanced_autodiff#custom_gradients)

Comment: Hi @Lescurel, sorry for the late answer! Once I was able to solve my problem with your help, I forgot my question here. The custom gradients work! :)